# react native maps not displayed when development apk is built , but running fine in expo go

Tags: react-native, expo, apk, react-native-maps

[image]this is my app.json file

```
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/Icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },

      "package": "com.atomz.app",
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "<my api key is here>"
        }
      }
```

i'am trying to build development apk in expo , im using react-native-maps , i have given the , apikey ,in app.json file , and enabled google maps for android too ,
i have given the SHA-1 key also fro the development build suggested by expo

All standard Expo templates use a debug keystore with fingerprint 5E:8F:16:06:2E:A3:CD:2C:4A:0D:54:78:76:BA:A6:F3:8C:AB:F6:25, that you can enter directly in the Google Cloud Credential Manager.

it is working fine and im able to see the maps in the expo go app ,
but when i build apk and test it in my phone , im getting only google logo in the maps page
can anyone help me with this please
thank you

this is my code

```
<View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          // onPress={Keyboard.dismiss()}
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
          style={styles.map}
          initialRegion={{
            latitude: lati,
            longitude: longi,
            latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
            longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
          }}
          ref={mapRef}
        >
</MapView>
<View>
```

this is my style

```
 container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  map: {
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    // width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
    // height: Dimensions.get("window").height,
    position:'absolute'
  }
```

Comment: 0

i used the SHA-1 key provided by the project expo credentials and it worked for me , thank you all

Answer (score 0):

This is because `Google Maps API` is not free.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/usage-and-billing#pricing-for-product

Although, maps will work on `iOS` anyway, because of `Apple Maps`.

All your styles are corect, this is an issue with API. Check if you have completed all the steps below: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/#deploying-google-maps-to-an-android-standalone

Comment: yes i have enabled billing , and  have completed the steps

Comment: Did you check your API key or commited changes?

Comment: It wasn't always like that right? It recently became payed? Is that the reason I get a blank map?

Answer (score 0):

If you're encountering issues in Production only, but not development, and are unable to pinpoint the error (because you can't see logs), I suggest using `Sentry.io` to capture and log production errors.

Expo has official docs to integrate it into your project.
https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-sentry/

Alone, you get crash reporting logged but in your situation, if perhaps your app isn't actually 'crashing', you can use Sentry's `CaptureConsole` integration to also capture logs to help troubleshoot.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73047272/4886040

Give these a go and you should be able to pinpoint exactly why it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

i used the SHA-1 key provided by the project expo credentials and it worked for me , thank you all

Comment: can you elaborate on that please? I am having the same issue. it would be nice if you provide how you get your SHA-1 key from where and put it where etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had this working for Android but not iOS, and I discovered I had made a mistake in my config. For Android the config is

```
 "android": {
   "config": {
      "googleMaps": {
        "apiKey": "<my api key is here>"
      }
    }
  }
```

but for iOS its a little different

```
 "ios": {
   "config": {
      "googleMapsApiKey": "<my api key is here>"
    }
  }
```

Its does state this in the [docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/map-view/#ios), but the difference can easily be missed