# expo go display react native maps but development build shows blank screen

Tags: react-native, google-api, expo, react-native-maps

I have used SHA-1 from the expo dashboard (or from eas credential) while creating a google API key and using it for react native maps, but still having issues with the development build. (blank screen with google logo at the bottom). When I open the app using expo go it displays maps but once having build apk and installed it real device it does not display the map but a blank screen. Here is the same issue but I could not find an answer.

[React Native Maps Blank Screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73564272/react-native-maps-not-displayed-when-development-apk-is-built-but-running-fine/75129006#75129006)

After creating the Google API key with SHA-1, I was expecting to see maps in the app installed on a real device.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Expo SDK 47, try using version 45 or lower once and see if it works, doing this , you may face issue running your app using expo go if you have the latest version installed, try downloading an older version from internet and then run the app. Google Maps seems not to be working with latest Expo SDKS

Answer (score 0):

MapType props, is 'none'? Change to 'standard'. Attezione!  using Apple Maps in mapType: "standard" will sometimes crash when you background the app or switch into another app. This is only an issue in XCode using Metal API Validation, and won't happen in production. To eliminate this problem even while debugging in XCode, go to Edit Scheme... -> Run (Debug) -> Diagnostics and uncheck Metal -> API Validation. (h/t @Simon-TechForm).

Comment: Im using managed expo, where does mapType: "standard" go?