# How to catch *all* errors and exceptions with Sentry?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, console, sentry

Out of 24 errors that appear in the `console` of my page in Chrome, Sentry only records one.

I have followed the documentation and ensured that Sentry is loaded and initialized in the `<head>` of the page, after jQuery, but before our CMS vendor code and custom bundles:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://browser.sentry-cdn.com/5.8.0/bundle.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"</script>
<script>
  Sentry.init({
    dsn: "https://...@.../..."
  });
</script>
<script src="..."></script>
```

I have also patched Sentry as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633580/how-to-report-console-error-with-sentry) to copy `console.error()` with `Sentry.captureMessage()`, so that I am now seeing *three* messages in Sentry.

But I am still struggling with three types of errors:

- `Uncaught TypeError`
- error in a JS file coming from our CMS
- some very particular `<img>` `srcset` errors

[image: console output]

As regards the `srcset` errors: I have already added `onerror` handlers to the images. They are called in some cases, but not in this particular case (the `srcset` attribute has a space in the filename which violates the syntax); admittedly, this problem should rather be reported to the Chrome dev team than fixed in Sentry.

I have tried to capture these errors myself and redirect them manually to Sentry, but none of the following listeners even catches them in Chrome (sorry for the `.join()`, just test code, I didn't beautify it):

```
window.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {
  alert(["window.onerror", errorMsg, url, lineNumber].join());
  return true;
};

window.addEventListener("unhandledrejection", function (e) {
  alert(["window: Unhandled Rejection", e.reason.message].join());
});

window.addEventListener("rejectionhandled", function (e) {
  alert(["window: rejectionhandled", e.reason.message].join());
});

window.addEventListener("error", function (e) {
  alert(["window: Error", e.reason.message].join());
});

$.error = function (message) {
  alert(["jQuery error", message].join());
};
```

So: am I missing anything (some Sentry config setting, other browser events that I should capture, etc.)?

Comment: Hi, did you ever get round to resolving this?  I'm having the same issues.